# how to set Chrome Cookies Timezone?? default time zone utc

Tags: php, google-chrome

I had test my website login function. I'm in Asia. `UTC+8`

I using php `time()` and format that... the time is no problem.

But if I push `F12` to check cookies value. That time is `UTC+0`

How to set the Chrome cookies timezone to `UTC+8`???

this time is utc+0... how to change to utc+8
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you doing to get the timezone in Chrome (when you write, "But if I push F12 to check cookies value. That time is UTC+0")?

Comment: I added a image in this topic.